# Saving mongoid model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I hove the following mongoid model:

```
class Exercise
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, :type => String
  field :description, :type => String

  belongs_to :group

  validates_presence_of :name, :description
end
```

I want to persist a model through my controller:

```
class ExercisesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def create
    @exercise = Exercise.create(params[:exercise])
    @exercise.save!
    respond_with @exercise
  end
end
```

When I pass the following json:

```
"{\"_id\":\"50064f2e26a31829ca000001\",\"description\":\"Do something\",\"group_id\":\"4fbc6f5a26a3181742000004\",\"name\":\"Preacher curls\"}"
```

I get this error:

> Failure/Error: post :create, :exercise => exercise.to_json
>        NoMethodError:
>          undefined method `reject' for #

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?r

Answer (score 0):

pass as this

```
params[:excercise] = JSON.parse("{\"_id\":\"50064f2e26a31829ca000001\",\"description\":\"Do something\",\"group_id\":\"4fbc6f5a26a3181742000004\",\"name\":\"Preacher curls\"}")
```